# Why does coordinate (X) [midway] doesn’t work, while coordinate [midway] (X) is fine?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Why doesn’t the `coordinate` see the options if they are behind the name? With `nodes` it makes no difference wether the options follow or precede the name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,3) -- ++(5,0) node (A) [midway] (A) {};
    \draw (0,2) -- ++(5,0) node (B) [midway] {};
    \draw (0,1) -- ++(5,0) coordinate [midway] (C);
    \draw (0,0) -- ++(5,0) coordinate (D) [midway];
    \foreach \C in {A,B,C}
        \fill (\C) [green!70!black] circle [radius=1pt] node [above] {\C\ is ok};
    \fill (D) [red!70!black] circle [radius=1pt] node [above] {D is not};
    \fill (2.5,0) [green!70!black] circle [radius=1pt] node [above] {D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coordinate options]

The point `D` should be in the middle of the line as the others but it seems like the `coordinate` can’t see the `midway` option. I guess the reason is the way how TikZ parses a coordinate (starting with `coor…` ending with `…)`?) but I wonder if this is a bug and should be reported …

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I guess the reason is the way how TikZ parses a coordinate (starting with `coor…` ending with `…)`?) […]

What is a `coordinate`?
A coordinate is nothing but a `node` shape that doesn’t have anything except one coordinate (the `.center` anchor is the same as every other anchor).

How does TikZ work?
It scans its way through the whole `\path` and looks out for key words or sequences of characters in a combination of `\futurelet`s and `ifnextchar`s.

If it encounters a `c` it tests for a following `i` (→ `circle`) or a following `h` (→ `child`), otherwise it must (should) be an `o` that follows.
It tests than whether another `o` follows, otherwise it must be `cos`.

If everything works (i.e. `co` without a following `o`) `\tikz@coordinate` will be called.

```
% Syntax for coordinates:
% coordinate[options] (coordinate name) at (point)
% where ``at (point)'' is optional
\def\tikz@coordinate ordinate{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar[{\tikz@@coordinate@opt}{\tikz@@coordinate@opt[]}}
\def\tikz@@coordinate@opt[#1]{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar({\tikz@@coordinate[#1]}
  {\tikz@fig ode[shape=coordinate,#1]{}}}%}
\def\tikz@@coordinate[#1](#2){%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar a{\tikz@@coordinate@at[#1](#2)}
  {\tikz@fig ode[shape=coordinate,#1](#2){}}}
\def\tikz@@coordinate@at[#1](#2)a{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar t{\tikz@@coordinate@@at[#1](#2)a}%
  {\tikz@fig ode[shape=coordinate,#1](#2){}a}%
}
```

The macro `\tikz@coordinate` (that gobbles `ordinate`) then checks for an `[` (or assumes an option-less coordinate, ergo an empty `[]`). TikZ allows at this point only `coordinate [optional arguments] (optional name)` (and the `at` part at the end that I will leave out now). If this sequence is found (with or without `at`) an actual node is made with he absolute final (empty) node text (which is ignored in the case of a `coordinate` anyway).

The node text `{}` is absolutely final on the node path operator in a path. After that, every option used is applied to the path (like `[draw]`). In your example the `[midway]` is set for the path (which is the default anyway) and does only apply to nodes/coordinates between a path operator (like `--`) and the target coordinate.

The `\tikz@fig ode` macro works a little bit different because it always tests for options `[`, a name `(` and a position `at`. Those can be mixed freely as it works similar to the whole path which is ended with `;`.

Another way to look at it is to use:

```
\draw (0,1) -- ++(5,0) coordinate [midway, red] (C);
\draw (0,0) -- ++(5,0) coordinate (D) [midway, red];
```

In the first line the coordinate (which doesn’t have a path) would be red, in the second case, the path is red as if you would have written `\draw[red]`.

---

> […] but I wonder if this is a bug and should be reported …

Well, how would you signalize the end of a `coordinate` path operation? TikZ defines

```
…             coordinate          [<options>]   (<name>)    at (<position>)  …

^                 ^                   ^            ^         ^        ^      ^
rest of path  specifies a coord.   optional    optional       optional    rest of path
```

in exactly this order with one of the optional sequences being the final part of the coordinate. It doesn’t even allow

```
coordinate at (<somewhere>) [<options>] (<name>)
```

but it does

```
node[shape=coordinate] at (<somewhere) [<options>]
               (<name>) [<other options>] (<overwriting the previous set name>) {}
```

Comment: This is a great answer an it validates what I suspected.

Comment: @Tobi From T.Tantau in the node code **% A label text always ``ends'' the node.** and a `\coordinate` always has the implicit `{}` as a node.