# Using a coordinate with a pin, on an edge with TiKz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to get a `pin` `edge` to touch another `edge`, under the influence of `shorten`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[s/.style={->,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex}]
   \node (a) at (180:1) {$a$};
   \node (b) at (270:1) {$b$};
   \path[s,bend right=10] (a) edge node[pin={[pin edge={line to,-,shorten >=0ex,shorten <=0ex}]45:test}]{} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yields

[image: pin edge not touching edge]

This is due to the fact that the node created has an amount of space, so I thought of doing a *coordinate* style:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[s/.style={->,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex}]
   \node (a) at (180:1) {$a$};
   \node (b) at (270:1) {$b$};
   \path[s,bend right=10] (a) edge node[coordinate,pin={[pin edge={line to,-,shorten >=0ex,shorten <=0ex}]45:test}]{} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

... which leads to this funny looking construction, where the first edge looses the `s` style, but keeps the `bend left` property:

[image: edges touch, but first edge is drawn wrong]

Just for fun I tried using `coordinate` instead of `node[coordinate]`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[s/.style={->,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex}]
   \node (a) at (180:1) {$a$};
   \node (b) at (270:1) {$b$};
   \path[s,bend right=10] (a) edge coordinate[pin={[pin edge={line to,-,shorten >=0ex,shorten <=0ex}]45:test}] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which was clearly a bad idea

[image: have no idea what happened here]

Comment: The problem with `coordinate[…] (b)` is that `(b)` is taken as the name for the new coordinate and the actual target is missing. (There should be an error message saying that `(`, `+`, `coordinate` or `node` was expected.) So, it actually would work if you do `coordinate[…] (<throwaway>) (b)`. For reference: [Why does `coordinate (X) [midway]` doesn’t work, while `coordinate [midway] (X)` is fine?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/128612)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to avoid the inheritance problems altogether and simply do things in two steps:

```
\path [s, bend right] (a) edge coordinate (@aux) (b);
\path [late options={name=@aux, pin=45:test}];
```

The `@aux` coordinate name is just a throwaway (`aux`iliary) as you probably won’t reference the coordinate again anyway.

The `late options` option is explained in the [PGF manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf#page=200) on pages 200f.

> Most of these options will have no effect since you cannot change the appearance of the node, that is, you cannot change a red node into a green node using late options. However, giving the `append after command` and `prefix after command` options inside the `<options>` (directly or indirectly) does have the desired effect: The given path gets executed with
>   the `\tikzlastnode` set to the determined node.
>
> The net effect of all this is that you can provide, say, the `label` option inside the `<options>` to a add a label to a node that has already been constructed. Likewise, you can use the `on chain` option to make an already `<existing node>` part of a chain.

Notes:

- `pin` is very similar to a `label`.
- `\chainin [<options>] (<existing name>)` actually is just a short-cut for

  ```
  \path (<existing name>) [late options={on chain,every chain in,<options>}]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Damn... been battling this on/off all day, and just after I posted the question I got an idea. Just set the size to 0 an emulate the `coordinate` style, duh!

This can of cause be done with `inner sep=0, minimum size=0`.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[s/.style={->,shorten >=1ex,shorten <=1ex}]
   \node (a) at (180:1) {$a$};
   \node (b) at (270:1) {$b$};
   \path[s,bend right=10] (a) edge node[inner sep=0,minimum size=0,pin={[pin edge={line to,-,shorten >=0ex,shorten <=0ex}]45:test}]{} (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

although the result is pretty close, it is not quite there.

[image: almost touching]

Therefore I am reluctant to accept my own answer.

Comment: Almost there: If you also set `outer sep=0pt`, the lines will touch.

Comment: It might be easier to avoid the inheritance problems and simply do things in two steps: `\path[s,bend right] (a) edge coordinate (@aux) (b); \path [late options={name=@aux,pin=45:test}];`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel nice trick! Since it is indifferent to styles etc, it is a way more elegant solution. If you post an answer I will accept that. Also, is the `@` imbued with special magical powers?

Comment: I have posted an answer. The `@` has no special effect here and is only used to highlight the throwaway character of the node/coordinate name.